# How can a function from one namespace be included in another namespace?

Tags: clojure

I have a function defined in one namespace

```
(ns package.sub)

(defn func1[]....)
```

I wish to include it in another namespace... `(ns package.main)`

so that I can use it from another library:

```
(ns app.core
  (:use [package.main :only [func1]))
```

What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but what not just use it from the package it's in (:use [package.sub :only [func1]])?  I mean its either that, change the namespace to main, or move the function...

Comment: it basically to package everything up for the end user... `midje` and `useful` both do it using macros... but I don't understand what they did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it is generally encouraged to simply have the users require the namespace the function actually lives in, although as you point out some libraries still do "re-export" Vars. The main reason re-exporting is potentially problematic is that there is no actual re-exporting in Clojure -- you're getting separate Vars which happen to share the same root value (see end of this answer).

If you insist on exporting the function from `package.main`, but defining it in `package.sub`, you can simply create a Var to hold it in `package.main`:

```
(ns package.main
  (:require [package.sub :as sub]))

(def foo sub/foo)
```

This has the downside of not transferring metadata to the new Var, which is unfortunate for this use case, as metadata on `defn`-introduced Vars holds information used to support a pleasant REPL experience. All the custom macros like `defalias` and `immigrate` basically do the equivalent of the `def` form above (perhaps using `intern` and/or calling methods for resetting the root bindings of the target Vars) while taking care to transfer metadata; you can pick whichever one you like best and use it.

Note that the target Vars are completely separate from the source Vars and may be e.g. rebound separately with `binding` if marked `:dynamic`, given differing root values etc.